# Bootstrap Select Not formatting properly

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, select, search

I have a weird styling problem that does not seem be resolved no matter what I do. When I inspect the page and look at the elements I can see the 'width' of the div is correct but the actual select does not go to the correct width even tho I have data-width set and you can see it in the inspect tool also.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="search-box search-box-dark">

     <form asp-action="post">

            <div class="select-default">
        <select 
            name="scale" 
            id="scaleID" 
            class="selectpicker"
            data-width="100%"
            asp-for="scaleId"
            asp-items="Model.scl" 
            data-live-search="true">
                 <option value="">Choose Scale</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Adding `form-control` to the class also makes the div go to the correct width with a background but the 'button' that is visible in the inspect tool is not wide engough.

[image]

Comment: what is your actual requirement??

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I wan the small white area you can see to be the full width like the other ones. The 'blue' you can see is no there it's just from the inspect tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

'''class="select-default"'''

from div and see if select width property works!